# CSS display table – total cell widths under 100%; where is the remaining width?

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand CSS display: table. What happens when the cells/columns within the table don't make 100%? For example within the table in the JSFiddle:

```
.flag { max-width: 10%;}
.country_manager {max-width: 55%;min-width: 35%;}
.score1 { max-width: 5%;}
.score2 { max-width: 5%;}
```

At most that cover's 75% of the table width, so how is it decided where the remaining width goes?

In [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2CwG/3/) I have blank cells at either side assuming one or both would take up the remaining space.
Without them, [there isn't a lot of difference](http://jsfiddle.net/J2CwG/2/).

The reason I ask is that I'd like the country section to be slightly adjustable, and if it is smaller, I'd like the table contents to be centered with even spacing to either side.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is no different from how browsers allocate width to actual table columns, and there is a prior question about this [How is extra width in a table divided up among columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178267/how-is-extra-width-in-a-table-divided-up-among-columns). Alas, there is no good answer there either, but a link to further documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, this behaviour is inconsistent across two very good, standards-committed browsers -- Chrome and Firefox. Firefox appears to actually use the percentages you give, so if you have 75% of the width set in your containing elements, it'll only fill 75% of the table and center the elements in the middle. Chrome, on the other hand, will assume that the width is 100%, and represent the columns as filling the full width.

e.g. if you have two max-widths, both set at 5%, Firefox would show each at 5% width and have 45% empty each on the right and left. Chrome would be 100% full, and each element would be 50% width.

Based on the browser inconsistency alone, I'd avoid ever not letting them add up. Perhaps you could use a :before and :after pseudo-class to create a spacer area with the remaining with, and force it to be centered?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using different code structure. You see, tables are useful in displaying chunks of data. But if you want to have a website layout I would split website into header / content / footer. And after that use divs with absolute positioning to represent those block you've shown

Answer (score 0):

i think and test this css code.

```
<style>
 .table {
     margin-top:5%;
     padding-top:5%;
     padding-bottom:5%;
     background-color: #ddd;
     width: 70%;
     height: 50%;
     position: absolute;
     display:table;
     font-size: 2vh;
     text-align: center;
     overflow:hidden;
  }
   .row {
        display:table-row;
        width:100%;
        height:40%;
    }

  .row_small {
     display:table-row;
     width:100%;
     height:5%;
     background-color: red;
     padding:10px 0;
    }

   .blank {
   display:table-cell;
    }

   .flag {
    display:table-cell;
    width:10%;
    max-width:10%;
    background-color: orange;
    }

   .country_manager {
   display:table-cell;
   max-width: 55%;
   min-width: 35%;
    }

   .country {
     display:table-cell;
     width: 100%;
     height:70%;
     background-color: yellow;
     float: left;

    }

   .manager {
     display:table-cell;
     height:30%;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: pink;
    float: left;

   }

  .score1 {
       display:table-cell;
       width:5%;
       max-width:5%;
       background-color: blue;
     }

     .score2 {
        display:table-cell;
        width:5%;
        max-width:5%;
        background-color: green;
      }

    .title {
          display:table-cell;
          padding:10px 0;
          color:#fff;
      }

     .ref_contain{
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     height: 15%;
      }
    .ref {
     background-color: #800080;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     display: table-cell;
     float: left;
     padding: 10px 0;
     position: absolute;
     text-align: left;
     text-indent: 133px;
    width: 100%;
    }
   </style>
    //write your html 

   <div class="table">
    <div class="row_small">
        <div class="blank">1</div>
        <div class="title">2</div>
        <div class="title">3</div>
        <div class="title">AET</div>
        <div class="title">Pens</div>
        <div class="blank">blank1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="blank">blank2</div>
        <div class="flag">Flag</div>

        <div class="country_manager">
            <div class="country">Country</div>
            <div class="manager">Manager</div>
        </div>  
        <div class="score1">1</div>
        <div class="score2">7</div>
        <div class="blank">blank3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="blank">blank4</div>
        <div class="flag">Flag</div>
        <div class="country_manager">
            <div class="country">Country</div>
            <div class="manager">Manager</div>
        </div>
        <div class="score1">1</div>
        <div class="score2">7</div>
        <div class="blank">blank5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="ref_contain">
        <div class="ref">Ref</div>
    </div>

</div>
```